# Eclipse Indigo - Cannot install Android ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I try to install the Android Developer Tool, I get the following error.

> Software being installed: Android
>   Development Tools
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486)   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   11.0.0.v201105251008-128486) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but
>   it could not be found

I also found that adding the WST package does not help. I get the following,

> Cannot complete the install because
>   one or more required items could not
>   be found.   Software being installed:
>   Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.3.0
>   2.3.0.r37v201106211634 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.3.0.r37v201106211634)   Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse
>   3.7 2.3.2.r37v201106211634 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.3.2.r37v201106211634) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0' but
>   it could not be found   Cannot satisfy
>   dependency:
>       From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.3.0 2.3.0.r37v201106211634 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.3.0.r37v201106211634)
>       To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.3.2

I'm running Eclipse Indigo 64bit version. Could someone point me in the right direction? Or tell me where to find that missing package.

Comment: The ADT [system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) specify that it works with Eclipse 3.5, and doesn't mention 3.6 or 3.7 at all. If you want to play safe, I strongly suggest you to download Eclipse 3.5 32 bit. ADT doesn't work with Eclipse 64 bit

Comment: @Augusto I'm running ADT with Eclipse x64

Comment: I might be seriously confused, but I'm quite sure I had a lot of grief about 2 years ago trying to install it on Eclipse 64b, until I read that it only worked on Eclipse 32b... This might have changed in the mean time, or I might need to get my head checked :)... or both

Comment: @Augusto "Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) or greater" is supported. This can be understood as supporting the latest release.

Comment: If you use AVG antivirus you should disable it. Only this helped me out (thanks @Lizozom from another question about this error).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Head over to `Help` -> `Install New Software`. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.

(Had to do the same yesterday after getting Indigo)

Comment: Now I just get a load of messages about conflicting dependencies... Damn you java!

Comment: This helped me out. Also, updates were failing silently until I ran Eclipse.exe as an Administrator. It probably would not have worked if I didnt have that option.

Comment: Do not forget to select "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem. This helped for me:

1. Go to Help->Install Software
2. Click on "Available Software Sites"
3. Click on Add:
     Name: "Helios"
     Location: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios"
4. Try to install Android Development Tools

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to fix it for me. I guess it just needed to know of the location of the Helios repository for dependencies. Not knowing the inner workings I cannot guess more. Alas this does not feel like a very 'clean' solution but it has got me up and running. (Eclipse Classic 3.7 Win32 build running on Win 7 Pro x64).

Comment: same here, I had no eclipse indigo repo and used your solution and it works with android adt r12, eclipse 3.7, amd 64 bit server jvm. Thx

Comment: Update : It works much fast than eclipse 3.6 for me, with settings for 3.6 from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Comment: This does not work on 3.7. It just says "Duplicate location". Same with ..releases/indigo. And if you update anyway you get messages about conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 17):

I got around the `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0` issue by taking the following steps:

- Go to help
- Install New Software: Add Name: Indigo Location: "**http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo**"
- Select '**WST Server Adapters**' under '`Web, XML, Java,...`" (last name in list)
- Accept licensing agreement
- Restart Eclipse
- Resume procedure to install `ADT`

It worked for me, hope it does for you too.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me too, using Eclipse Classic Indigo.

Comment: In my experience, this works, but, simply as http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo was added to the software repos. (See Alex's answer)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue.  The other solutions here didn't work for me because I couldn't even see the Indigo / Helios update repos.  The problem was that Eclipse was in Program Files, but I wasn't running it as an administrator.

Comment: Same issue here on Windows 7. Moved Eclipse out of Program Files and problem went away. Alternatively, you could always run Eclipse as Administrator as you appear to have done.

Answer (score 10):

So I got indigo, and then :
    Go to Help->Install New Software
    Click on Add: Name: "Indigo" Location: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo"
    Try to install Android Development Tools (as you will see, only 1 option out of 4 will appear - this is normal for Indigo)

Comment: Thanks. Strangely, on my Ubuntu 11.10 , with the default Indigo install, this repository wasn't available.  I had to add it by hand. Wierd.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure you have the option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software". This option is located in the lower left corner on the first screen after choosing Help/Add New Software. This is unchecked by default. This WILL FIX the issue if it was unchecked.

The plugin will install in 3.7 32bit and 64bit.

Answer (score 5):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse depends on other specific Eclipse components, such as WST. Your installation of Eclipse may not yet include all of them, but they can be easily installed by following these instructions. Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

```
 Select Help > Install New Software...

Click the link for Available Software Sites.
Ensure there is an update site named Indigo. 

If this is not present, click Add... and 
enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo for the Location.

Now go through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and install 
the plugin's dependencies.
```

Comment: This worked for me - By default eclipse Indigo had this checked but it also had a few other software sites checked too. I unchecked all and only checked the indigo site and the android site and it installed on my 64 bit install fine.

Answer (score 3):

I've also had this problem. I solved it by going to:

Clicking -> available software sites
  Select "Helios" and click Reload.
  Select "ADT Plugin" and click Reload.
Then went back, tried again and it worked.

If you still can't get it working there are directions for doing it manually here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

(also: I'm using 3.7 64x, it's working fine, not having any issues.)

Answer (score 3):

I tried installing and got the same error (using the new "marketplace").  I tried the typical Help->install new software...  then where it says "Work with:"  I entered:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

followed all the prompts and everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Execute eclipse with root level

**$sudo /opt/eclipse/eclipse**

Answer (score 1):

Go to  Help->Install Software.
Add the following link  http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ .

Then press next and accept the license, it installs some of the software required then you will be gud to go.

After the eclipse restarts it prompts you to download the android sdk required or give the path of android sdk if already it is downloaded.

This works all the time what ever may be the version.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, Eclipse + ADT (ADT Bundle) is now provided as a single package,

[Developer.Android:ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for me. Having all the correct update sites in "available sites" was not enough to tell Eclipse how to find its dependencies.

Using Fedora 14 and Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1, I had to follow these steps to make the installation working:

1. Check and install "Linux Tools" from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
2. Check and install "Linux Tools" from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201109230900

After restarting Eclipse, I was able to finaly install the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the posts but unfortunatley none of the above solved my problem. Eventually what got it all working for me was to download eclipse indigo 3.7.2 and (this is very important) EXTRACT IT DIRECTLY INTO MY PROGRAMS FOLDER. Before I would extract it to my desktop and copy into the programs folder (C:\Program Files) but I would jus get an error message saying "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" when trying to run eclipse.

After extracting eclipse directly to my programs folder I ran it and added the ADT plugin the way reccomended in on [the android site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) and so far all is working well :)

I'm on a windows 7 x64 machine and had jre-7u2-windows-x64.exe, jdk-7u2-windows-x64.exe and [installer_r16-windows.exe](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installed before extracting eclipse.

I hope this can help someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in Indigo Eclipse now, there's a video showing someone [install android eclipse](http://www.idimmu.net/2013/03/23/install-android-eclipse/) on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Still pretty bewildering.  It seems some combination of the above suggestions worked in Eclipse 3.7.2.

First, I had to move to a network that dl-ssl.google.com hasn't blocked (this is an ongoing problem with the Google server)
(Easy with a laptop, less so with my tower.)

**The Eclipse folks should look at this problem.**
The user sees an error, something about a missing package "org.eclipse.wst.sse.core', say.
There are 50 or so plugin repositories listed.
*which* of these is the one that has this package???
*None* has a name containing a 'wst' or 'sse'.

**This is very poor.**  There needs to be a way for the user to associate the error message 
with a repository solution.

Anyway: after some hunt-and-peck I ended up selecting
(and reloading each repository, and with *Contact all update sites during install to find required software* checked)

- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  (ADT Plugin, which I
  added according to the Google instructions)
- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios (Helios Milestone
  repository)
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6
  (Eclipse Project Test Site)

One of these provided the packages needed for the Android plugin . Best guess: Helios.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer (by Sathya) is also applicable in Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items
could not be found.  Software currently installed: Shared profile 
1.0.0.1308118821836 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 
1.0.0.1308118821836) Missing requirement: Shared profile 
1.0.0.1308118821836 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 
1.0.0.1308118821836) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse
```

Run As Administrator !!!

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse Classic or Galileo is the two you can use.  The other Eclipse IDE are not meant to program or interpret JAVA in the same way.  Download either 64x or 32x will work on Classic or Galileo on a PC.  Just make sure you PC can handle which version of Eclipse you download.

Comment: Not true, you can use helio and indigo on 32bit and 64bit.