# Who is the better for Android development ? Eclipse Helios or Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: android, eclipse

which is the best Eclipse Helios or Eclipse Galileo?

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume Helios succeeds Galileo and would include bugfixes for Galileo. Other than that they're probably just as good as each other. What do you define as 'best' though?

Comment: You could go for Indigo.

see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482268/eclipse-indigo-cannot-install-android-adt-plugin

Comment: I've been noticing a LOT of down votes on totally reasonable questions lately. I'm wondering what the story is on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest is Eclipse Indigo. Use that, its quite good. The performance is also up to the mark.

Comment: is it latest one after Helios ?

Comment: protip: since Galileo, they've been released in alphabetical order: Galileo, Helios, Indigo, Juno.