# Can't install Android ADT using Eclipse 'Indigo'

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse Indigo - Cannot install Android ADT Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482268/eclipse-indigo-cannot-install-android-adt-plugin)

I could not find an answer for the common problem of not getting a clean install of the ADT from the newest version of Eclipse 'Indigo'.  Without going into detail, I would like to know if anyone has had success installing latest versions on Windows 7.  I am reverting to Helios and will wait a reply for possible solution or step-by-step instructions after Indigo is better established with Android ADT.  The download location https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ may need to be updated for Indigo.

Comment: SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138460759

Comment: You might have chosen an eclipse edition where some depencies are missing. Which one did you download? I can confirm that it works with the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" out of the box.

Comment: it works fine on XP and everybody else seems to be ok with it.  Some of us had issues with upgrading helios to indigo so a clean install is recommended. I cheated and copied the indigo files over the top of Helios which worked really well

Answer (score 1):

I have it running on Windows 7 Pro without issues. I followed the instructions here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Look in the section "Downloading the ADT Plugin". I did that and it worked right out of the box for me.

What issues are you seeing?

Comment: You may have had the additional components already installed but I was doing a clean install on a new computer.  Helios version had no problems with exactly the same procedure.  Thanks for letting me know about your results with Indigo.

Comment: Actually I don't think I had anything installed because my hard drive had just died. All i installed was Java and then Eclipse. Good luck!