# How to resolve the issue of android resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i'm new to android, i'm getting this error. please help me in providing the solution

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better you explain clearly that what is your problem, when you are getting this and what you are trying.

Comment: When i create a simple project, i got this error... i have done nothing...

Comment: just clean your project.

Comment: i did that also, still its appearing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**R cannot be resolved to a variable**  When we will get this error.

R.java is an automatically generated file to hold all your resources used in project. It will be created under **gen** folder when you build your project. While building your project it will assign IDs to each resource you used in project and keeps them in their individual classes (drawable, id, layout, etc.) and creates a file R.java, place it in your package.

If anything wrong in your resource files (drawables or xml layouts) it won't generate R.java file.

So please check it once. I too faced same problem previously.

Comment: when you create a sample project, layout will be proper.. i have not done any changes.. :(

Answer (score 2):

All the resources in Android are referenced by an 'id'. This 'id' is generated automatically in the file 'R.java', which itself is generated in automatically in 'gen' folder, once you build the project.
So, what you have to do is just 'Build your Project'

Comment: Have you tried restarting your eclipse ?
Also try deleting the 'gen' folder and clean the project

Comment: Yes saurabha, i did tat also... no progress :(:(... since yest this prob s bugging me... what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Build you project and you will get `you.package.name.R.java` file - and just import it.

Comment: When i add, i get "The import You.are.hell.R cannot be resolved" error wat to do?

Comment: You have some problems in xml or drawables - solve it first, than R file will be generated

Comment: You have only one xml file? What do you have in `res` folder except `layout/main.xml`?

Comment: Hi, i have these many files drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png
drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
layout\main.xml
values\strings.xml

Comment: So, you just create new "Hello, world" app? If so try to create new one - without proguard and with package name in low case.

Comment: One issue is solved, but another issue arisen "Description Resource Path Location Type Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse-god\koko\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist unknown Android Packaging Problem "

Answer (score 1):

I think I saw the problem. You are having 2 folders named 'res'.
Just delete the res folder which is empty and Clean, build the project

Comment: i got two errors, R not found and Error in executing aapt.exe

Answer (score 1):

if your gen folder is still missing then check whether you have done installation properly and then check if you have any error on any of the xml files in your project

refer following links

[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

[No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)

[No generated R.java file in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085959/no-generated-r-java-file-in-my-project)

http://www.joshuakerr.com/2009/10/23/android-and-the-missing-gen-folder/

Comment: I have done standalone installation , i have installed V2.1 platform and the eclipse version is Indigo..  is this error platform dependent ?

Comment: Hey, setup seems fine. I reinstalled everything... i dont no what to do

Comment: see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482268/eclipse-indigo-cannot-install-android-adt-plugin] .Android works fine on eclipse galileo

Comment: I tried on Helios, i installed fresh ADK, in tat i choose only android dev kit i.e 2nd option.. still giving same problem

Comment: One issue is solved, but another issue arisen "Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse-god\koko\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist unknown Android Packaging Problem
"

Comment: i think u now need to set java path in your ide

Comment: Thanks, issue is solved. it was totally related to installation. Eclipse acts crazy sometimes, i don't no why it is :(

Comment: so to thanks atleast accept a answer which helped you to resolve your problem