# Issue in installing ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi i am using Eclipse Helios, to install the Android .
while installing the ADT plugin, i am getting this long error message.

Kindly suggest a solution for this.

Error message

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)   Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee
>   1.3.0.20100617-0521)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)

Comment: Perhaps this answer help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482268/eclipse-indigo-cannot-install-android-adt-plugin

Comment: Go to Help -> Install New Software. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse ... choose Help > Check for Updates 
and select any updates for the eclipse platform.... 
Try installing the ADT plugin again... 
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Plain Eclipse for Java, Avoid using eclipse for Java EE Developers

Comment: There's no problem using Eclipse for Java EE Developers and ADT together. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed anything else after you installed Eclipse for Java EE Developers? It looks like something is requiring an older version of Eclipse UI and won't accept a newer version.

Comment: Got it up and running ,you can say its like a trick, Go to Help -> Install New Software. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.